# How do the targeting mechanics of Ahri's Ultimate work?

Tags: league-of-legends

I play Ahri a lot but her style is so fast that I can't really tell what happens in these situations.

**If I use my ultimate next to an Invisible Shaco or Twitch does it deal damage to them?**

**If they are next to minions what are the priorities if they are invisible?**

And with **Brushes**. If an enemy champion is inside a Brush and you know he is in there and you use your ult but you're still outside the brush (in this case you don't have vision of him yet) **does your ult damage go through the brush to the enemy or you must have vision of him?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I use my ultimate next to an Invis Shaco or Twitch does it deal damage to them?

No, the ultimate only targets visible champions.

> If they are next to minions what are the priorities if they are invisible?

The ultimate prioritizes champions

> Does your ult damage go through the brush to the enemy or you must have vision of him?

You must have vision on them.

[source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ahri)

Comment: derp of me. I went to read the wiki and didn't read visible there. Thanks for the answer.